# Is it possible to use linux laptop as universal passthrough usb sniffing device?

Tags: linux, usb, sniffing

we sometimes need a device to sniff usb data communication between various devices. I know there should be some solution using Wireshark and Usbcap but this requires installing all the programs on particular PC.

Is there a possibility to use a linux laptop and two usb connecting cables so the laptop would behave as "junction-box" so it would let the data go through in both directions so any of the connected devices would not notice the sniffer. The sniffer laptop would log all the data going through.

Is that possible? We also though about building a dedicated device - probably Arduino based but this would make it possible to use almost any laptop.

thanks

Comment: Without installing software on the other devices? No. Also, you usually cannot easily connect two "Hosts" with a simple USB cable (although solutions are available).

Comment: Yes, without additional SW on the devices. One is usually some sensor connected via usb and second a PC with particular Windows SW. Goal is to capture communication between those devices and possibly replace the Windows machine with some MCU or embedded PC in future.

Comment: also read http://stackoverflow.com/a/39641370/1778421

Answer (score 2):

No. `USB` controllers used in personal computers support `USB Host` operation mode only.